# How to encode raw BGR video to H264 with an NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: opencv, h.264, nvidia, video-encoding

I am trying to encode a raw video to H264 format, but NVENC can only take YUV video as input and the latest version which can take BGR need driver version 358 which has not been released in linux.

So is there any other method which can use GPU to encode an BGR raw video?

I also tested the OpenCV GPU sample which use NVCUVID decoder which has been removed from CUDA 6.5. so it can not work anymore.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no connection between NVENC and CUDA. NVENC is an indepent hardware feature of Kepler and Maxwell GPUs. On the other hand, NVCUVID *is* based on CUDA, but is a video *decoder*. This question refers to video *encoding* and thus seems unrelated to CUDA, in which case the subject line should be modified and the [cuda] tag removed. This question seems to be asking for a software recommendation, which would make it off-topic here. Please clarify the question.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks, I am sure NVENC works based on CUDA because it can not work without CUDA toolkit. And in former OpenCV, there is a function  gpu::VideoWriter_GPU::write which can encode video, and it is implemented via NVCUVID. but this can not work with CUDA above 6.5. So I want to ask if there is any lib can do the same work as former OpenCV function.

Comment: As @njuffa (an NVIDIA employee) has already told you, NVENC is independent of CUDA. It has its [own SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) and *does not require CUDA*.

Comment: @talonmies: njuffa is a *former* NVIDIA employee.

Comment: @njuffa: My humble apologies. I didn't know you had moved on to greener pastures. I hope that won't stop your posting pearls of numerical wisdom amongst us mere mortals. I have learned a *lot* from looking at your code over the years.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for the kind words. There is no need to apologize, I merely wanted to make sure my comments were not interpreted as some sort of "official" statement on behalf on NVIDIA.